# time function in c++ by reference

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I was working on a function that rewrites the values of a time struct accordingly (if minutes are 128 it will change to 2 hours and 8 minutes)

don't mind too much the actual function right now, my problem seems to be with the declaration/parameters/struct itself.

Erors:

1. Error (active)   E0070   incomplete type is not allowed
2. Error (active)   E0266   "time" is ambiguous
3. Error (active)   E0065   expected a ';'

what have I done wrong?

thanks.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
//#include<math.h>
//void canonify(time&);
using namespace std;
//
typedef struct time
{
    int h, min, sec;
};
//
const int full = 60;
//
void canonify(time& pre)  // eror1 and eror2
{                         // eror3
pre.min += pre.sec / full;
pre.h += pre.min/ full;
pre.sec %= full;
pre.min %= full;
}
void main()
{
    time a;
    a.h = 3;
    a.min = 128;
    a.sec = 70;
    canonify(a);
    cout << a.h <<":"<< a.min <<":"<< a.sec << endl;
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that the logic is wrong as well: instead of "second = minute*full - pre.sec;", it should be "second = pre.sec - minute*full;" or just "second = pre.sec % full;"

Comment: "`typedef struct`" is meaningless in C++. Get rid of it. Which C++ textbook are you using, that offers code examples that are so wrong? It's a bad textbook, you should switch to a different one.

Comment: `void main` is deprecated for ages, please use `int main()` and return an acceptable value to the environment (`return 0;`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Struct name 'time' is causing the conflict. You can change name of the struct to something else and replace typedef struct to struct only otherwise it will be ignored by compiler itself.

This code is working for me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
//#include<math.h>
//void canonify(ti&);
using namespace std;
//
struct ti                               //change
{
    int h, min, sec;
};
//
const int full = 60;
//
void canonify(ti &pre)                 //change
{
    int hour;
    int minute;
    int second;
    minute = pre.sec / full;
    second = minute * full - pre.sec;
    hour = pre.min / full;
    minute = hour * full - pre.min;
    pre.h = hour;
    pre.min = minute;
    pre.sec = second;
}
int main()
{
    ti a;                              //change
    a.h = 3;
    a.min = 128;
    a.sec = 70;
    canonify(a);
    cout << a.h << ":" << a.min << ":" << a.sec << endl;
}
```